# Mouseout and Mouseenter jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover, mouseout

I used the jQuery mouseout and mouseenter function. But is not working good. Because when you go fast over the items. I get verry crazy effects. I used this code:

```
$('.hover').css('opacity', 1);
    $('.controlNav li').mouseover(function() {
        $('.hover', this).css({ display: 'block' }).animate({ top: -73, opacity: 1 }, 450, 'swing' );
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $('.hover', this).css({ display: 'none' }).animate({ top: -60, opacity: 0 });
    });
```

How can i fix my problem?

Comment: You said you used `mouseout` and `mouseenter` but your code contains `mouseout` and `mouseover`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added in `.stop()` just before the animation which will stop the animation in place and should stop the jumping.

```
$('.controlNav li').mouseover(function() {
    $('.hover', this).css({ display: 'block' }).stop().animate({ top: -73, opacity: 1 }, 450, 'swing' );
}).mouseout(function(){
    $('.hover', this).css({ display: 'none' }).stop().animate({ top: -60, opacity: 0 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem originaly is not `mouseout` or `mouseover` events. They are working as they should to work. It means even if you mouse over the element for just `1ms` it will work.

Solution for this problem is delaying the action. You should wait a certain amount of miliseconds to do what you want happens.

You can do it manually or you can just use [jQuery hover intent plug](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) in that implemented this very nice and easy to use.

It's better to not use `mouseout` or `mouseover` event and use jQuery `.hover()` (if you are using the plug in `.hoverIntent()` for more clean and readable code.

Answer (score 0):

`.mouseover()` and `.mouseout()` give strange results because `mouseover()` fires more than once while your mouse is still inside the element.  Simple mouse movement will trigger it again & again.

`.mouseenter()` and `.mouseleave()` are better because they are only supposed to fire one time upon entering or leaving the element.  However, they still do not seem to function as well as `.hover()` which combines them together into one method.

Also adding a `.stop()` will stop the current animation before starting a new one.  `.stop(true, false)` will clear anything in the animation queue and not allow the current animation to complete.

```
$('.controlNav li').hover(
    function() {
        $('.hover', this).css({ display: 'block' }).stop(true, false).animate({ top: -73, opacity: 1 }, 450, 'swing' );
},
    function() {
        $('.hover', this).css({ display: 'none' }).stop(true, false).animate({ top: -60, opacity: 0 });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/hover/

http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Answer (score 0):

set some variable as mutex, like:

```
var isActive = false;
('.hover').css('opacity', 1);
    $('.controlNav li').mouseover(function() {
        if(isActive) return false;
        isActivce = true;
        $('.hover', this).css({ display: 'block' }).animate({ top: -73, opacity: 1, complete: function(){isActive = false} }, 450, 'swing' );
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $('.hover', this).css({ display: 'none' }).animate({ top: -60, opacity: 0 });
    });
```