# jQuery: How to limit code execution to one execution per "cycle"

Tags: jquery

I wrote something like this.

```
$(this).hover(function(){
            if($(this).offset().left <= $('.list-group').offset().left)
            {
                $(this).animate({left: '+=7px'}, 50);
            }
        }, function(){
            if($(this).offset().left > $('.list-group').offset().left)
            {
            $(this).animate({left: '-=7px'}, 50);
            }
        });
```

What I wanted to achieve was a moving menu item after hover, but the problem is that it sometimes doesn't return to the place. It goes right and stays there, it goes left and stays there until refresh or another mouseenter, especially when you hover multiple times in short period of time. I tried limiting possibility of moving to only a certain condition, like:

```
if($(this).offset().left > $('.list-group').offset().left + 6)
```

But it still doesn't do the trick.
I'll be very grateful for a help :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mouseout and Mouseenter jquery function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042905/mouseout-and-mouseenter-jquery-function)

Comment: I'm not really but I think that is a duplicate. Use .stop() function, it'll maybe worked.

Comment: Oh, a duplicate it was. Thank you very much, works like a charm now :D